# Sending image to PHP server via post

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send an image from my phone gallery to the server.
but i get empty $_FILES and empty $_POST

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        URL url=new URL("server_url");
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);

                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=");
                        conn.setReadTimeout(35000);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(35000);

                        // directly let .compress write binary image data
                        // to the output-stream
                        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);

                        os.flush();
                        os.close();

                        System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());

                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String line = "";
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null)
                            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                        responseStreamReader.close();

                        String response = stringBuilder.toString();
                       Log.d("WEDDING","response "+response);

                        conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

how should i construct the POST request for sending the image.
I have also tried to use loopj library but this doesn't help

Thank you !

Comment: I haven't done this in android, but have on other mobile platforms and applications. You need to base64 encode the image, set that's as a post variable to the server, then base64 decode it on your php server and save that data to file. You then have you're image on your server

Comment: I also ran into this problem. After a lot of research, I found the issue of page's **content-type**. I personally advised you to first check the content type of the php file...!
And if don't mind, can you share the working method which only sending the json request(not image) to the server through that I can diagnose the issue...!